# DexExpress XPO WCF DataStoreService Poor Performance

Tags: wcf, iis, devexpress

This is not a question actually. I just want to share my experience that I have encountered while using DevExpress XPO WCF DataStoreService which is the WCF was too slow and IIS Worker were stuck with more than 100 requests in average 200,000 milliseconds.

My code was based on this tutorial:
https://supportcenter.devexpress.com/ticket/details/e4930/how-to-connect-to-a-remote-data-service-instead-of-using-a-direct-database-connection

So, the issue was here:

```
DataStore = XpoDefault.GetConnectionProvider(connectionString, AutoCreateOption.DatabaseAndSchema);
```

the option "AutoCreateOption.DatabaseAndSchema" was the issue that make the poor performance, then I changed it to "AutoCreateOption.None". Voila, the performance was much much better, no more stuck requests, every request occurred less than 20 seconds for large data synchronization.

So, I doubt the process of checking and recreate schema made the SQL unresponsive and stuck the request in the IIS. My solution was moving the Update schema to a separate module and only update on demand.

Again, this is not a question. I hope it can solve somebody's WCF issue as well.

Answer (score 0):

Solution is change AutoCreateOption.DatabaseAndSchema to AutoCreateOption.None